# Problems with local copy of socket.io.min.js

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I want to use flask and web sockets on a client server system not always connected to the internet. I have made local copies of jQuery-1.11.1.min.js and socket.io.min.js. When I use them, I get the problem:

> [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'a.transport.onClose')    (anonymous function)
>   (socket.io.min.js:2:15385)

in the browser. If I load the js libs from the web, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a satisfying answer, but the order matters!!

From the web:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js">
</script>
```

works OK, but

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='socket.io.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Gives the above problem...

If I reverse the order as follows then everything works:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='socket.io.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Maybe a timing issue... Does not leave me with a good feeling, but at least I can progress.